# Angular: Access variables from outside scope of ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am having issues accessing variables (attached to $scope) inside ng-repeat loop. My ng-repeat is as follows:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="Message in Messages">
    <p>{{ Message.Sender ChattingWith}}</p>
</div>
```

I can use ChattingWith variable outside the ng-repeat but can't use it inside for some reason. I have used `$parent.ChattingWith` without any luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use like <p>{{ Message.Sender}} {{ChattingWith}}</p>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write code like this:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="Message in Messages">
    <p>{{ Message.Sender + ChattingWith}}</p>
</div>
```

This will solve the problem.